# How did Rod find Chris?

Tags: plot-explanation, get-out

In the ending of Get Out, after Rod shows up in a police car to save the day, Chris asks Rod the following:

> **Rod**: I told you not to go in that house.
>
> **Chris**: **I mean... How did you find me?**
>
> **Rod**: **I'm TS motherfucking A. We handle shit.   That's what we do.
>   Consider this situation ... fucking handled.**

It's a hilarious answer which makes for one of the movie's best moments, but it still doesn't answer the question.

**How did Rod find Chris at the end of *Get Out*?**

Answer (score 5):

There are no sourced/concrete answers, so here are some possibilities:

- Rod has a friend (friend of a friend) in the FBI or CIA who could track people through the cellphone which Rod used to talk to Chris in previous scenes.
- Rod did a simple search based on the name **Armitage**, which seems to be a popular family, and found the address online. Chris even says:

  > I'm at the Armitage's house.

  When trying to call the police earlier indicating it's a very popular family/house.
- Since Rod was taking care of Chris dog, Chris probably left his address in case the dog got sick or something happened with it.

Comment: Yep. Where they were going wasn't exactly kept secret.